# Get WP All Export row ID

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, export

Is there a way to get current row's ID/number while exporting orders with WP All Export plugin (http://www.wpallimport.com/export/)?

First row would contains the columns' name, but we need that the first column contains a growing number, so second row (which contains first order details) first column value should be 1; third row (which contains second order details) first column value should be 2; etc...

Situation is complicated because orders export limit is 50 (In each iteration, process 50 records), so if you have 60 orders 51. order's first column should be 51, not 1.

I have tried with $i variable and $_SESSION[] variable too, but this are not the best solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've got a solution from plugin's developers:

1. Add this code to theme's functions.php file

`// run a function before export starts, it deletes counter value from DB
add_action('pmxe_before_export', 'wp_all_export_pmxe_before_export', 10, 1);
function wp_all_export_pmxe_before_export($export_id)
{
    delete_option('wp_all_export_current_row');
}`

2. Add this to All Export plugin's Edit Export screen under " Export the value returned by a PHP function" section

`// update counter value while exporting
function get_row_number()
{
    $current = get_option('wp_all_export_current_row', 1);
    update_option('wp_all_export_current_row', $current + 1);
    return $current;
}`